# ASP.NET MVC Web Application Running on IIS with Entity Framework Trying to Retrieve Oracle Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, iis, windows-authentication

Here is the error message I got:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

I have been trying to figure out why an error occurs when trying to access Oracle via Entity Framework from ASP.NET MVC Web Application running on IIS 8.5.9600.16384 using Windows Authentication. I've tried everything from adding NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE, NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM or just NETWORK SERVICE schemas to Oracle, changing DTC settings on IIS, changing Application Pool's Identity, removing and installing Oracle Client as well as ODT with ODAC on both the workstation and the web server and just about everything I can find on the first few pages of [this Google search results](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20underlying%20provider%20failed%20on%20open&oq=the%20underlying%20provider%20failed%20on%20open&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.1471j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Upon further investigation of the error, I noticed that the web application has spitted out an inner exception message which reads as follows:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

The trace log for Oracle.ManagedAccess.Client shows that the correct Windows Username is trying to login.

I've used an Oracle schema credentials (`User Id=USERID;Password=<password>;`) to connect instead of the Windows Authentication (`User Id=/;`), and the test was proven to be successful. However, this won't do me any good as I need to have each Windows user connect under his/her own Oracle schema due to my database environment requirements.

How can I make this work with the Windows Authentication?